# Why can I apply an indexer to an ICollection in VB.Net, but not in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, icollection

Was converting some code from VB.Net to C#, when I came across this, in some code using the Ionic Zip library:

```
Dim zipEntry1 As ZipEntry = zipFile1.Entries(0)
```

Simple enough:

```
ZipEntry zipEntry1 = zipFile1.Entries[0];
```

I get this error on C#:

> *Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection'*

Both are using the same version of the DLL, on both `zipFile1.Entries` is a generic `ICollection`.

I have tested the below on VB.Net, and it builds successfullly:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Imports Ionic.Zip

Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim zipFile1 = ZipFile.Read("C:\test")
        Dim zipEntry = zipFile1.Entries(0)

    End Sub

End Module
```

This does not build:

```
using Ionic.Zip;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var zipFile1 = ZipFile.Read(@"C:\test");
            var zipEntry = zipFile1.Entries[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Why does this happen, and is there a way around it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Bizarrely enough, it looks like VB has special support for `IEnumerable<T>` and implicitly provides an indexer which *actually* calls [`Enumerable.ElementAtOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb494386.aspx). `ICollection<T>` extends `IEnumerable<T>`, so the same facility exists there. `ICollection<T>` doesn't provide a "real" indexer, hence the problem when you try using it from C#.

Sample program:

```
Option Strict On

Public Class Test
    Public Shared Sub Main(args As String())
      Dim x as System.Collections.Generic.ICollection(Of String) = args
      Console.WriteLine(x(0))
    End Sub
End Class
```

Generated IL for Main:

```
.method public static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.STAThreadAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 ) 
  // Code size       15 (0xf)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init 
      (class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<string> V_0)
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  stloc.0
  IL_0002:  ldloc.0
  IL_0003:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0004:  call       !!0
     [System.Core]System.Linq.Enumerable::ElementAtOrDefault<string>(
        class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0>,
        int32)
  IL_0009:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  IL_000e:  ret
} // end of method Test::Main
```

I find it *very* odd that VB provides this implicitly - it's really dangerous to make it *look* like it's fine to index into a collection which doesn't necessarily supply an efficient indexing operation.

Of course, you can call `ElementAtOrDefault` yourself, if you're happy with what that does.

Comment: I guess the idea that you *can't* do it in C# is more of a leftover from C, where you'd assert that the `[]` operator can efficiently index a sequence using the x86's addressing modes. Whereas in VB, you say that you want the 3rd element, and you get the 3rd element.

Comment: @dialer: Well the provision of an indexer doesn't *have* to be terribly efficient - but I don't like the idea of it being implicit, with no indication to the caller that this isn't being provided by the declaring class. There are times where it could be *dramatically* worse - imagine if you used a for loop over the index instead of a foreach loop, for something which had to read a text file each time to get to the nth line (or whatever).

Comment: This will get very weird if you access an item by index on a `Set` for example.

Answer (score 7):

Strictly viewed, `ICollection<T>` is an interface to an *unordered* collection of elements (more precisely, a collection whose elements cannot individually be accessed by their index). That is just *by definition*.

But you can still use LINQ's `ElementAt(int index)` extension method. That would just iterate through all elements `index` times every time you call it (so it is generally slower).

NOTE: `ICollection<T>` is not to be confused with `Collection<T>`. The latter implements `IList<T>` (among other things),  which by definition *does* specify that each element can be accessed by its index.

Comment: +1 for answering the `is there a way around it` part, thanks very much, would still love to know why though.

Comment: @JMK see update. It's just how the `ICollection<T>` interface is defined.

Comment: @dialer: Your answer doesn't explain why VB allows it (or what it does).

Answer (score 0):

VB has long had the idea of a *default member* for it's classes, which for collections is always the member *Item*().

Comment: This nearly always just corresponds to the indexer for the class, which is not at all a VB-specific thing.  The VB shortcut demonstrated in this thread for 'ElementAtOrDefault' is the weird VB-specific thing.

Comment: Except in this case it's not Item but ElementAt

Answer (score 0):

`zipFile1.Entries(0)` invokes the so-called *Default Query Indexer*, which is a little-known feature defined in the [VB language specification](https://github.com/dotnet/vblang/blob/189d2c15703b91a9241ce9ade46e6bc24b193cd9/spec/expressions.md):

> **Default Query Indexer**
>
> Every queryable collection type whose element type is T and does not already have a default property is considered to have a default property of the following general form:
>
> ```
> Public ReadOnly Default Property Item(index As Integer) As T
>     Get
>         Return Me.ElementAtOrDefault(index)
>     End Get
> End Property
> ```