# Translate from VB to C# for loop

Tags: c#

I used a popular online code converter to go from VB to C# and the C# is not working on this for loop. Can any C# experts see the problem?

More specifically intellisense is telling me that `CustomerRoles()` cannot be used like a method. It works fine in VB.

VB:

```vb
 Dim Roles As New List(Of String)
 For x As Integer = 0 To EngineContext.Current.Resolve(Of IWorkContext)().CurrentCustomer.CustomerRoles().Count - 1
     Roles.Add(EngineContext.Current.Resolve(Of IWorkContext)().CurrentCustomer.CustomerRoles(x).Name)
     ddlRoles.Items.Add(EngineContext.Current.Resolve(Of IWorkContext)().CurrentCustomer.CustomerRoles(x).Name)
 Next
```

C# (this is not working) :

```cs
List<string> Roles = new List<string>();
for (int x = 0; x <= EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IWorkContext>().CurrentCustomer.CustomerRoles().Count - 1; x++) {
  Roles.Add(EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IWorkContext>().CurrentCustomer.CustomerRoles(x).Name);
  ddlRoles.Items.Add(EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IWorkContext>().CurrentCustomer.CustomerRoles(x).Name);
}
```

Comment: Remove the () from custom roles. It's a property then change (x) to [x] you're accessing by index.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace

```
CustomerRoles(x).Name
```

with

```
CustomerRoles[x].Name
```

You access the indexer of arrays (or lists)  with squared brackets instead of paranthesis in C#.

If it's not a collection but a property or field you just have to remove the paranthesis:

```
CustomerRoles.Name
```

If that doesn't work(for whatever reason) you can try `Enumerable.ElementAt`:

```
CustomerRoles.ElementAt(x).Name
```

That works with any kind of `IEnumerable<T>` even if it doesn't implement `IList<T>`(needed for the indexer).

Comment: it now says I cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type system.collections.generic.icollection<Nop.Core.Domain.Customers.CustomerRole>

Comment: of type system.collections.generic.icollection<Nop.Core.Domain.Customers.CustomerRole>

Comment: @mlg74: try to remove the paranthesis  or use `ElementAt`, edited my answer.

Comment: ElementAt didn't work. I am trying to do it with remove paranthesis, but its not liking that so far. i get an error on "Name" if i do that

Comment: maybe I am missing an assembly or reference...it says

Comment: @mlg74: `ElementAt` is from `Enumerable` which is in `System.Linq`. So you need to add `using System.Linq;` at the top of the file.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
C#(this is not working)
List<string> Roles = new List<string>();
for (int x = 0; x <= EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IWorkContext>().CurrentCustomer.CustomerRoles.Count - 1; x++) {
    Roles.Add(EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IWorkContext>().CurrentCustomer.CustomerRoles[x].Name);
    ddlRoles.Items.Add(EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IWorkContext>().CurrentCustomer.CustomerRoles[x].Name);
}
```

Ok i've tried in VB `CustomerRoles(x)` is equivalent to `CustomerRoles.ElementAtOrDefault(x);` in c#.

Comment: i get error cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type system.collections.generic.icollection<Nop.Core.Domain.Customers.CustomerRole>

Comment: I think it was a `IList<T>`. In VB you can access the elements by index in a collection??? Can you change it's type to IList<Nop.Core.Domain.Customers.CustomerRole> ???

Comment: How do I change it?  IList<Nop.Core.Domain.Customers.CustomerRole>,<string> Roles = newe IList<string>();??

Comment: I see, but it says i may be missing an assemble or reference

Comment: `Using System.Linq` in using directives it's all you need.

Comment: _"Ok i've tried in VB CustomerRoles(x) is equivalent to CustomerRoles.ElementAtOrDefault(x); in c#"_ It is _not_ equivalent, you can use `ElementAt`(or `ElementAtOrDefault`) also in VB.NET. It is just a more dynamic way to get an element at a specified index. If it's an `IList<T>`(like array or list) the indexer is used, otherwise `ElementAt` will enumerate the sequnce to find the element.

Comment: in VS2012 intellisense show me like it was the `ElementAtOrDefault` extension method. Have you found some link that explain how work in VB?

Comment: Ok after some search I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15864783/why-can-i-apply-an-indexer-to-an-icollection-in-vb-net-but-not-in-c-sharp.